# Encrypting personal backup on public shared drive

Tags: backup, encryption

I work in a company where we have an internal shared network drive with almost 50 TB of space. Me and my colleagues use it for saving non-sensitive work-related stuff but many use it also for storing their personal non-sensitive stuff.

I would like to take advantage of the drive's large capacity and use it to store my personal backup, which is about 3 TB. All the drive is accessible by everyone in the company and we don't have separate private folders for each user.

How can I best encrypt my personal backup to be sure that no one will be able to decrypt it, bruteforce it or just access it in any other way? My colleagues are IT security professionals and are quite nosey, but I don't want to ask them this question in order not to bring their attention to the fact that I will be occupying that much disk space.

*Notes: This is going to be 3rd backup of my personal data. I already have one on my personal NAS and the other one stored at a paid cloud service. I am accepting the risk that a colleague may delete my encrypted personal backup.*

Comment: If they can already read your folder then encrypting a folder is not going to help.  As soon as you decrypt it for your use, everyone will also be able to look at it for that period of time.

Comment: I strongly suggest you do not keep personal data on company servers. This could easily backfire on you.

Comment: Create a VHDX, mount it, then encrypt it with BitLocker.

Comment: @RohitGupta Before decrypting it, I would first download it to my personal hard drive. Of course I would never decrypt it on the shared drive, which they can read.

Comment: @John How can it backfire on me if it is encrypted and noone's gonna know what it contains. They just gonna see a big file.

Comment: If you manage to encrypt it you may be OK .  I keep personal and company things far apart

Comment: @yssup that's the point: they will see a huge file without knowing what it contains, and they generally don't like that. And as raised in the answer, if there is some incremental backup of this 50TB space, each time you will update your file it will possibly be entirely backed up in turn, and the ITs will wonder why the incremental backup takes so much time... But OK, you probably know better than us what you can do or not in your company.

Comment: @RohitGupta that's mostly wrong. When opened, an encrypted disk image for instance is not decrypted on the disk where it is stored. It is decrypted on the fly by the software/driver that has opened it from a client PC, and the decrypted data only reside in the RAM of the client PC.

Answer (score 1):

You really need to get permission first or you could land up in trouble.  You havn't specified your OS or how often you need yo access the data.

The easiest way may be to use something like 7zip to create a compressed archive making sure you use a strong passphrase and AES algorythm.

An alternative might be to create a Veracrypt file (or LUKS if you use Linux). The key to tjis is to use a complex passphrase and/or a key file stored elsewhere. A 12 character **random** password with uppercase,lowecase and numbers will take hundeds to thousands of years to crack with known technology.

BTW, if your IT department is on tje ball they will likely be able to know who and when this was uploaded, and you could get into trouble at some point in the future if the sysadmin starts looking for big files to delete because the disk is gettingvfull.  50tb of reliable disk is not cheap, and 6% likely wont go unnoticed - especially if they are doing offsite backups.

Comment: Thanks, I already obtained the permission. What is the difference in using 7zip and Veracrypt file?

Comment: 7zip is a compressed archive - minimal file size, but difficult to modify.  Veracrypt is an encrypted container so much easier to make changes to (you add the decryption key, open it and treat it like a hard disk)- its  bigger and more complex to set up, but cpuld be way faster then copying 3tb of data every time you want to update the backup.

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit more on security of each option?

Comment: Nope. Google AES.

Answer (score 0):

I am sorta doing this same thing. Like user Ramhound has already said:
Create a VHDX, encrypt with bitlocker (or veracrypt even) copy to shared folder.

Process would be:

1. Run disk management (right click start button on win 10/11 click disk mgmt)
2. Click 'Action' then 'Create VHD' select size and type - dynamic & vhdx is better i think.
3. Enter or browse to some local folder / drive and give a name etc and click create.
4. Once created, double click to mount it. Then right click & select bitlocker.. or start button & type bitlocker and select the mounted disk and encrypt it with a password
5. Copy data.
6. Unmount and copy/move it to the shared network folder/drive.
7. When you want to access it you will have to copy it back to local drive and then double click it and it will ask for password and unlock.

I have been trying to get some solution where it can decrypt only the files i access.
Boxcryptor should be able to do that but i havent tried yet.
Tried EFS (It's the built-in encrypted file system in windows) but it has other issues.

Essentially if its one big image like a vhdx or partition image then it has to be copied back from the network to be decrypted. It cant be decrypted on the remote computer and left there. It could still be decrypted on the fly by copying each file to $TEMP on access and then decrypted but somehow i am unable to get that working.